# TNonblockingServerTransport not implemented with Thrift C# library

Tags: c#, thrift

When using Apache Thrift [https://github.com/apache/thrift] to create a non blocking server in C#, the following Classes/Types cannot be recognized:

```
TNonblockingServerTransport
TNonblockingServer
```

I want to send command from my win10 laptop to control a time-consuming calculation performed on a high performance server (ubuntu). That's why I came to Apache Thrift. I have found the official C# version tutorial [https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/master/tutorial/csharp] and it works well. This tutorial uses the so-called Blocking Mode (TSimpleServer). But in my situation, the time-consuming calculation procedure should be interrupt-able. Consequently, I must use a non-blocking server.

The logic is simple. For the server, I used a private flag **forceStop**. If the Client call Stop(), **forceStop** will set to true and the calculation loop will break.

```
        // #Server#
        // Server Set-Up
        private void SetUp()
        {
         try
            {
                CalculatorHandler handler = new CalculatorHandler();
                Calculator.Processor processor = new 
                Calculator.Processor(handler);
                var serverTransport = new TServerSocket(9090);
                TServer server = new TSimpleServer(processor, serverTransport);

                // Use this for a multithreaded server
                // server = new TThreadPoolServer(processor, serverTransport);

                Console.WriteLine("Starting the server...");
                server.Serve();
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        private bool forceStop;
        public int TimeConsumingOperation(int n1, int n2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("add({0},{1})", n1, n2);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                //calculating
                Thread.Sleep(500);

                if (forceStop)
                {
                    Quit();
                }
            }
            return n1 + n2;
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            forceStop = true;
        }
```

```
// Client

// Button#1 Click callback
private void Button_Start_Click()
{
    client.TimeConsumingOperation(0,0);
}

// Button#2 Click callback
private void Button_Stop_Click()
{
    client.Stop();
}
//
```

I've found some useful examples in java [https://chamibuddhika.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/apache-thrift-quickstart-tutorial/]. I've try my best to convert the java code of non-block server to the corresponding C# code but I found that there seems to be no TNonblockingServerTransport in C#. Anyone could help me with this probelm?

```java
// Java Code
public class NonblockingServer {

    private void start() {
        try {
            TNonblockingServerTransport serverTransport = new TNonblockingServerSocket(7911);
            ArithmeticService.Processor processor = new ArithmeticService.Processor(new ArithmeticServiceImpl());

            TServer server = new TNonblockingServer(new TNonblockingServer.Args(serverTransport).
                    processor(processor));
            System.out.println("Starting server on port 7911 ...");
            server.serve();
        } catch (TTransportException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NonblockingServer srv = new NonblockingServer();
        srv.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually two answers to that question.

### Possible implementation

Your setup is flawed, to begin with.

```
    // #Server#
    // Server Set-Up

    private bool forceStop;

    public void Stop()
    {
        forceStop = true;
    }
```

Let's assume, we have two clients, both starting a new calculation. Now one client wants to abort. What happens?

The solution would be to structure it in a way where the calculation is a separate business logic object that is instantiated at `TimeConsumingOperation()` and made available to the client by some means, typically by returning some sort of ID.

When the client now wants to abort, it calls `Stop(calcualtionID)`. The server side logic now routes that call to the implementation and triggers whatever the abort mechanism might be, with C# is is probably a `CancellationToken`.

A third call would be needed to query the final results from the server end once the calculation has finished. Note that we still work with a `TSimpleServer` and the reason it works is because we avoid blocking calls by means of the API design.

### Nonblocking server

Yes, there is no implementation yet for C#. Since Thrift is Open Source, that probably simply means that there were nobody running into that use case so far and wanted to spend time on an implementation. That is not to say that such a use case may not exist.

What exists are

- Threaded and Threadpool servers
- `Task.Run(() => { your code })`

which may help to solve your use case. Also, when used with ASP.NET there is no need for a nonblocking server since the runtime offers enough support already for multiple connections.

### Bottom line

There are certain ways to work around that limitation you experierenced. One additional alternative could be to [become a contributor](http://thrift.apache.org/docs/HowToContribute) by porting one of the existing (e.g. Java) nonblocking implementation to [NetStd](https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/master/lib/netstd) (preferred, since C# and NetCore will mature into "deprecated" state with the next release and both be replaced by NetStd eventually)

Comment: clean and clear! Thx. Task.Run() is enough in my case.